# How can I extend a partition with nonadjacent unallocated space?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, gparted

This is my partition table:
[image]
How can I merge or resize my existing partition `/dev/sda9` (and `/dev/sda9` is my Ubuntu 14.04) with unallocated space? I don't want to lose my data.

I have tried to resize `/dev/sda9` partition but I am getting any free space as shown no leading free space:
[image]

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do that without Gparted having to literally rewrite most of the data on the disk.

A typical consumer HDD would be certified to have at least one "bit flip" error when rewriting an amount of data that large. Then there is also the matter of non-ECC RAM... The bottom line is *don't even think about doing this* unless you have a complete system image.

I consider that operation to be very high on the danger level, and personally, I wouldn't do it if it was my computer!

Partitions can never be extended backwards, only forwards.

What you *can* do however, is extend `dev/sda5`...

Comment: can i use it with my `/dev/sda9` after formatting to ext4 ? if yes , how?

Comment: @KaranChudasama - You mean if you formatted the unallocated space as its own partition?

Comment: yeah formatting to ext4 and mounting on my existing `/dev/sda9`

Comment: @KaranChudasama - Not exactly sure what you mean by "use it with `/dev/sda9`. It will show up as another drive, and you can store files on it...

Comment: creating it's own partition and mounting on `/dev/sda9` so that I can store my data

Comment: @KaranChudasama - AFAIK, you can't mount a partition inside of a partition. If you format it, you'll be able to use it in the same way as if it were an external drive.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**:- As per [AndroidDev](https://askubuntu.com/users/518562/android-dev), since it is a large amount of data that you will be moving, please be sure of sudden changes such as power outage, etc. Also if possible, back your data up before proceeding.

1. Delete `/dev/sda7`.
2. Right-click on `/dev/sda8`, then click "Resize/Move".
3. Cut the value from "Free space preceding (MiB)" and paste it to "Free space following (MiB)".
4. Click on "Resize".
5. Right-click on `/dev/sda9`, then click "Resize/Move".
6. Now, increase your partition size.

Comment: You really need to include a warning that this is a **VERY** dangerous operation.

Comment: @AndroidDev - It is not at all a **VERY** dangerous process. I do this kind of thing all the time. Though I will add a backup warning to my answer.

Comment: With all do respect, you don't consider rewriting most of the data to the disk (a process that takes HOURS) dangerous? You do release that the HDD is certified to have at least one "bit-flip" error when rewriting an amount of data that large?

Comment: @AndroidDev - I agree that it will take a long-time. Oh k, I understand your concern, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: And then there is the matter of non-ECC RAM as well. Bottom line, always make a backup first. Or else you have nobody to blame but yourself when you data goes up in flames.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create an ext4 partition in the unused space then use LVM (logical volume manager) to create a single volume that the system will see.  Look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm (see Resizing Partitions).  I'm no expert, but it seems a possible way to go.

Comment: The only problem with that is that his disk isn't setup with LVM. (I think?)

Comment: That's true.  It will need a bit of research, but if it can be done, it's a safe option.

Comment: Oh yes, no disagreement there. LVM is really good.